# Pass Environment variable to Data Properties

Tags: docker, tomcat

I'm trying to run tomcat in a container and want to pass `DB_HOST` as a environment variable.

I tried starting the container as `docker run -e DB_HOST='dbhost001' -p 8080:8080 image_id`. But that doesn't seem to work

`db.properties file:`

```
db.machine=${DB_HOST}
db.dbname=users
db.username=test
db.password=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Add `propertyConfigure` for `servlet xml file` like below:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

Modify db.properties file like below:

```
db.machine=${DB_HOST}
db.dbname=users
db.username=test
db.password=test
```

Pass the variable to tomcat as `CATALINA_OPTS="-Dkey=value"` when starting tomcat.

In my case it was docker container. So starting it as following worked.

```
docker run-e CATALINA_OPTS="-DDB_HOST=dbhost001" --name tomcat -p 8080:8080 -d tomcat7:0.0.1
```